# Entity Project Build Time

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, build-process

We have one solution with multiple projects.

One project has our entity model with 200+ tables.

Each time I build that project, VS 2012 takes too long at the "Build started" status till it continues the build process.

The problem is that this issue is happening even if we don't change any thing in that project.

So: each time we try to build any project that depend on the entity project it will take that long time even if nothing has changed in the entity project.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by turning off validation at compile time.

To get to that option: open the EDMX file, then right click on an empty area, then open properties window, then set the option: "Validate On Build" to False.

[image]

Comment: Note that development teams which use a build server and do branching and merging should be careful to make sure that the model is validated before the team's server build.  After merging an EDMX from one branch to another, open the model in the VS model editor so it will do a model validation.  Then the model can be checked in with confidence.